# Is there a better rank bound for fibered products?

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, profinite-groups

Let $G$ be a profinite group of rank $d \geq 2015$, which is a fibered product of two groups of rank at most $2$. That is, there exist closed normal subgroups $N_1, N_2 \lhd_c G$ with $N_1 \cap N_2 = \{1\}$ and $$\max\{d(G/N_1),  d(G/N_2)\} \leq 2.$$

Schreier's bound for the rank of an open subgroup $U \leq_o G$ is: $$d(U) \leq [G:U](d-1)+1.$$

Can we beat Schreier's bound in this case? That is:

Must there be some open subgroup $K \leq_o G$ with $d(K) < [G:K](d-1)+1$ ?

Comment: Why $d \geq 2015$?

Comment: @StefanKohl I am ready to assume that $d$ is arbitrarily big, but I am not sure how big should it be. Maybe even $d \geq 6$ is good enough.